# Wordpress theme options page query_posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am busy building a small theme options page for one of clients and need some help with an issue.

currently i have the option to manually put in IDS of wordpress pages to extract the data with `query_posts`

based on the theme options is creates a variable called `$euro_box_1_vehicles;`

my options are filled in as `32,39,43,54` in the input, and when I print this statement with echo, I get the same result.

When I just replace `array(32,39,43,45)` with `array($euro_box_1_vehicles)` it only returns one result.

```
<?php
    $vehicle1 = array(
        'post__in' => array(32,39,43,45),
        'post_type' => 'page',
    );

    query_posts( $vehicle1 ); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($euro_box_1_vehicles)` and let us know what gets printed.

Comment: When I echo var_dump = string(11) "32,39,43,45"

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, Added the result for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I echo var_dump = string(11) "32,39,43,45"

In which case, you need to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) `$vehicle1`, since `post__in` expects an array;

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => @explode(',', $vehicle1)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

> When I just replace array(32,39,43,45) with array($euro_box_1_vehicles) it only returns one result.

Shouldn't you replace `array(32,39,43,45)` with `$euro_box_1_vehicles` *not* `array($euro_box_1_vehicles`)?   The latter seems it would make a nested array with one argument, i.e. array(array(32,39,43,45)). Which is not what you want.

---

Old Answer....

If I read you right then query_posts() expects a list of IDs? (32,39,43,45)

But when you pass it $vehicle1 you are not giving it a list of IDs, but a 2-dimensional array.

```
<?php
    $vehicle1 = array(
        'post__in' => array(32,39,43,45),
        'post_type' => 'page',
    );

    query_posts( $vehicle1['post_in'] ); //use sub-array that contains list
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: No Eddie, @ApPel has got it right - query_posts() expects an array of arguments, and `post__in` is a particular argument that expects an array of IDs.